# How to know that the Buffer is completely read in NAudio

Tags: naudio

I am using NAudio for coding a software in C# and im using BufferedWaveProvider

```
var bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 2));
// AddSamples here
WaveOut wavPlayer = new WaveOut();
wavPlayer.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);
wavPlayer.Play();
```

How can i know that the buffer is completely read, or the exactly position now.
Since wavPlayer.Play() have been called, how can i get the current position.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `IWavePosition` interface can be used to tell you how much audio (in bytes) has been played so far by `WaveOut` - just call `GetPosition()`.

As for `BufferedWaveProvider`, if you set `ReadFully=false` then playback will automatically stop when you reach the end of buffered audio. You can also check the `BufferedBytes` property to see how much audio is queued up to be played

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you for your answer. I'm using IWavePosition but i met a problem that although when AddSamples, i only add 4096 bytes, it means that the BufferedBytes is 4096 but when i call GetPosition() function, the return values is 9600. i think that the returned value must always be smaller than 4096. 
Everytime i add Samples with 4096 bytes, but the returned value of GetPosition() is too big. Or my thinking was wrong. Please confirm it. Thank you.

Comment: BufferedWaveProvider is set up by default to keep playing silence after it runs out. GetPosition will return ever increasing amounts irrespective of whether you ever call AddSamples

Comment: Hi Mark. I am implementing by 2 tasks(asynchronous). The first one is used for handling the data and use AddSample to add data to the buffer. Each time 4096 bytes. the other one is used for playing sound. The first time when i addsample with 4096, when the waveout read to 3000th byte, i will add 4096 bytes. The process is Add-Read-Add-Read...but the sound must be smoothly. So i need the exactly position(when the wave out read to 3000th byte to add more 4096 bytes) of the waveout since i called waveout.Play(). So, with NAudio, can i resolve that problem. Thanks you.